# Stuck trying to loop through an array that is a subset of worksheets in my workbook

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am stuck on trying to create an array, or some type of object that I can use to loop through a subset of worksheets in my workbook.  What is the best way to create a list of worksheets that Excel can then loop to?  In my head, I was thinking, okay, I will just create an array and set it equal to the names of the workbooks I need.  However, when I try that, Excel complains about not having an object.  Is an array not an object in Excel?

Also, how should I declare an array that is a list of worksheets?  Variant?  String?

Can someone give me some ideas?

Here is the code I have below.  For now, please ignore the fact that I am using three different paste types.  That is because I was having trouble getting Excel to paste exactly what I need.  I will refine that later.

```
Sub CopyMacro3() 

    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet

    Dim vSheets As Variant

    Set pasteCell = Range("A2") 

    vSheets = Array("CAS-J30F-70LTV", "CAS-J30F-80LTV")

    For Each CurrentSheet In vSheets
        CurrentSheet.Activate
        Range("A1:T80").Copy
        Worksheets("print").Activate
        pasteCell.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        CurrentSheet.Activate
        Range("A1:T80").Copy
        Worksheets("print").Activate
        pasteCell.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        CurrentSheet.Activate
        Range("A1:T80").Copy
        Worksheets("print").Activate
        pasteCell.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Set pasteCell = pasteCell.Offset(0, 20)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!  I really appreciate it! I guess that putting the Array inside the Sheets() function is what tells VBA that it is an object.  The Array() must not be considered an object by itself in VBA I guess?  That makes sense with what Me How was saying about the Array being a list of strings and not a list objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a variable - you can just use:

```
for each currentSheet in Sheets(Array("CAS-J30F-70LTV", "CAS-J30F-80LTV"))
```

Comment: Yep - I missed the declaration of CurrentSheet.